# jQuery, AjaxForm and success option

Tags: ajax, jquery-plugins

I'm using the jQuery Form plugin and more specifically the ajaxForm method to hijack a normal form and post it using ajax.  I have a form with lots of rows.  Each row has **edit** and **delete** options and each section has an **add** option.  Hijacking the form I can work out on the server whether to add, edit or delete but would like the ability to know which button was pressed in the success method back in my JS.  Is this possible?

I know there are two params: responseText and statusText and that I can work out the button type in beforeSubmit **but I need it when the data is returned which button has been pressed**.  The reason is that I want to display a form in a light box for edit and add but for delete I want to do something different.  It seems a bit naff to check the data coming back to look for a certain string (not to mention flakey and unmaintainable).

Anyone know of a simple solution?

Comment: You could return json from server and handle responseText as json.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `beforeSubmit` option: it's a function that will get called, well, before submit. More importantly, it provides the data. You could look at the data and set a flag that would then be used within the success function. This isn't beautiful, but better than being coupled to the server's behavior.

In this situation, I have often just created two different forms-- one for update and one for delete. Then, instrument them separately.